WiFi randomly available with Intel AX200NGW
I have an HP ProBook x360 11 G5 EE running Arch Linux (kernel 6.10.6) and my WiFi controller (an Intel AX2000NGW) sometimes works, and sometimes doesn’t.
For instance, it worked sometimes between the end of June and mid-July (and simply rebooting was very often the solution), then worked perfectly fine between mid-July and one week ago. Now it no longer works, and rebooting doesn’t solve the problem. When I say “doesn’t work”, I mean “the WiFi icon doesn’t appear in GNOME’s bar nor in gnome-settings, and the airplane mode LED on the F12 key is on”.
I had this problem on two different HP ProBook x360 11 G5 EE with again two different Intel AX200NGW, on Windows 10, Ubuntu 22.10, Ubuntu 23.04, Ubuntu 23.10, Fedora 39, Fedora 40 and Arch Linux.
I find my problem similar to this one and this one, however my config isn’t a dual-boot, so I think my problem can’t be Windows fast-boot.
I don’t know exactly which info is relevant, but after reading other posts about similar problems, I think that all of the following is:
sudo lspci -v:
...

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

...

ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:81:40:3e:82:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

rfkill:
ID TYPE      DEVICE     SOFT     HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   débloqué débloqué
 1 wlan      phy0   débloqué débloqué

(“débloqué” means “unlocked”)
sudo dmesg | grep iwl:
[    4.165942] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x100530 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    4.166031] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI dev 2723/0084, rev=0x340, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.179982] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.180784] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.85be44d3.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.283459] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.425338] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    5.492215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 48:51:c5:f4:93:09
[    5.772184] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager:
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.3888] NetworkManager (version 1.48.8-1) is starting... (boot:28c0f5c2-22f7-4f68-8fc3-ed9590c66199)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.3889] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 20-connectivity.conf)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.4016] manager[0x6335ed9c35f0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7341] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7341] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "proxima"
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7345] dns-mgr: init: dns=default,systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7369] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7374] manager[0x6335ed9c35f0]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7374] manager[0x6335ed9c35f0]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7403] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7489] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7516] Loaded device plugin: NMOvsFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-ovs.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.7997] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8018] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8025] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.48.8-1/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8029] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8030] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8030] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.8038] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9901] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9904] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9918] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9924] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9931] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (8c1967f9-5f4e-4be5-b1a9-e96c53e700e7)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9942] manager: (enp3s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9956] settings: (enp3s0): created default wired connection 'Connexion filaire 1'
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9957] device (enp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9974] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9981] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185870.9992] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
sept. 01 11:17:50 proxima systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0009] ovsdb: disconnected from ovsdb
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0010] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0013] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0015] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0026] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0034] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.0352] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to EA:19:07:07:DF:C9 (scanning)
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.2665] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.2678] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.2774] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.3360] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.4775] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.4782] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.4870] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:51 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185871.7527] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 92:05:80:D0:36:D8 (scanning)
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.0154] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.0864] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.0922] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.1002] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.6137] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.6757] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.6762] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.6968] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:52 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185872.9570] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 62:5A:0D:35:51:E3 (scanning)
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.2453] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.3118] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.3124] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.3323] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.7983] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to F2:C8:F7:12:13:9D (scanning)
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8476] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8477] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlan0 created
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8480] manager: (p2p-dev-wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8486] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8491] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sept. 01 11:17:53 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185873.8497] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sept. 01 11:17:54 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185874.0082] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:54 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185874.0095] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-link-not-init', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
sept. 01 11:17:55 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185875.9270] agent-manager: agent[fc5dc1689c95e35f,:1.30/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/120]: agent registered
sept. 01 11:17:56 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185876.9973] manager: startup complete
sept. 01 11:18:08 proxima NetworkManager[519]: <info>  [1725185888.1750] agent-manager: agent[2f84b13203225f3c,:1.71/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered


Update: I just updated to kernel 6.10.7, and the WiFi adapter looks like it’s “rebooting” every few seconds, without connecting to any network. Here are the logs:

https://pastebin.com/sHWKcuGn

